# Serialization vs Raw Data

Tags: c#, image, serialization, stream

So I have an application sending a stream of images (think teamviewer) and as it currently stands it converts the images to Byte and then to Base64 and sends that as text through the StreamWriter. I've done a few things to improve latency and performance however I'm curious if I'm using the wrong tool for the job and if Serializing the images would reduce size and have less overhead.

Any advice would be appreciated :)